# Do i need to make an interface for inner classes?

Tags: java

I'm just learning about interfaces and their significance in java, is it necessary to create a interface for an inner class such as the program i have created below? The purpose of this class is just to be a vague archetype of the government and how it operates in its simplest form. I have created several methods adding laws, senators, and congress members. Does this code work for what i am trying to accomplish?

```
public class usaGov
{

private int sizeOfSenate = 105;
private int sizeOfCongress = 308;
private int amtOfLaws = 0;
private int law = 0;

void addSenateMember(int numberOfSenators)
{        
        sizeOfSenate = sizeOfSenate + numberOfSenators;
}

void addCongressMember(int numberOfCongressMembers)
{
    sizeOfCongress = sizeOfCongress + numberOfCongressMembers;
}    

void removeSenateMember(int numberOfSenators)
{        
       sizeOfSenate = sizeOfSenate - numberOfSenators;   
}

void removeCongressMember (int numberOfCongressMembers)
{
    sizeOfCongress = sizeOfCongress - numberOfCongressMembers;
}

void passLaw()
{
    if (law == 3)
    {
        amtOfLaws++;
    }

}

private class Senate 
{
void senateYes()
{
    int yes = 1; 
    law = law + yes;
}
void senateNo()
{
    int no = -1;
    law = law + no;
}

}
private class Congress
{ 
void congressYes()
{
    int yes = 1;
    law = law + yes;
}
void congressNo()
{
    int no = -1;
    law = law + no;
}
}
private class President
{
void presidentYes()
{
    int yes = 1;
    law = law + yes;
}
void presidentNo()
{
    int no = -1;
    law = law + no;
}
}    


}
```

Here is my interface:

```
public interface americanGov
{
void addSenateMember(int numberOfSenators);

void addCongressMember(int numberOfCongressMembers);

void removeSenateMember(int numberOfSenators);

void removeCongressMember (int numberOfCongressMembers);
}
```

Comment: What's the question? Ask a specific one?

Comment: sorry it said i didn't provide enough detail when i was trying to post. do i need to add onto my provided interface with methods for either of the inner classes?

Comment: okay. does that mean i would only add methods to future interfaces that include parameters?

Comment: when it comes to interfaces any function is defined in the interface should be implemented in the class that implements this interface, so you need to segregate the interfaces based on the functionality and where to use them

Comment: Your question is incomprehensible as it stands. If you were forced to re-formulate it as a single, clear, concise sentence, would would that sentence be?

Comment: @SaddamAbuGhaida so that means, i should create the interface before i create the class? 
Neilcoffey: i'm a beginner so i'm not sure if this will be much better: this code is not supposed to be functional, it's just stating that I semi-understand what class/interface syntax is. I wanted to know if the methods, that are in the inner classes, need to be stated/referenced in the interface along side the methods I stated/referenced in the usaGov class

Comment: Class names should be upper case. [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, all the law voting share the same code. You can significantly shorten and simplyfy the code by using only one class for all voting:

```
public class USAGOV {

    private VotingBody senate = new VotingBody(105);
    private VotingBody congress = new VotingBody(305);
    private VotingBody president = new VotingBody(1);

    void passLaw() {
        //logic to count votes from senate, congress and president
    }

    private class VotingBody {
        int members;
        int law;

        VotingBody(int members){
            this.members = members;
        }

        int getSize() {
            return members;
        }

        void voteYes() {
            int yes = 1;
            law = law + yes;
        }

        void voteNo() {
            int no = -1;
            law = law + no;
        }

        void addMembers(int members){
            this.members += members;
        }

        void removeMembers(int members){
            this.members -= members;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You only **need** to use intefaces when you at some point want to get multiple inheritance:

In Java, a class can only extend one other class, but it can implement multiple interfaces.

Any other use of interfaces is a **best practise** and code design thing.

The rule of thumb is: **If someone (including yourself) at some point in the future may want to write an alternate drop-in implementation of the same thing, use an interface**.

Inner classes usually do not fall into this categroy, unless you know you will have multiple inner implementations of the same thing. So using interfaces here might be overdoing it.

Answer (score 0):

You have created the interface and not implemented it. It will be of no use if you don't implement it.
Interfaces are abstract classes which can be used to achieve multiple inheritence or if you want to enforce a class implementing your interface to define the functions in it. These are the 2 main uses of an interface.